# ¿Como compruebo la existencia de un valor que está dentro de un arreglo, DENTRO de un diccionario?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Me encuentro haciendo un autómata que compruebe entrada de lenguaje. Mi código previo es el siguiente (Tomado de un ejemplo en una pagina web):

```
edges={                 #usamos mapas o diccionarios
       (1,'a'):2,
       (2,'a'):2,
       (2,'b'):3,
       (3,'b'):3,
       (3,'a'):4,
       (4,'c'):5}
aceptacion=[5]  #estado de aceptacion
def fsmsim(string, current, edges, aceptacion):#creamos la funcion
    if string == "":#cuando no encuentra nada
        return current in aceptacion #retorna true
    else:
        letter= string[0] # comienza con el primer caracter
        if(current,letter)in edges: # compara (estado,letra) se encuentra en edges
            destination=edges[(current,letter)]#si es asi destination tendra el nuevo valor estado
            remaining_string=string[1:]#comenzara a recorrer los demas caracteres
            return fsmsim(remaining_string,destination,edges,aceptacion)#funcion recursiva
        else:
            return False #si no es asi retorna falso
#hacemos una prueba
print(fsmsim("aaabbbac",1,edges,aceptacion))
```

Esto funciona sin problemas, pero solamente puedo comprobar un carácter.
Este es el código que estoy trabajando :

```
#Declaro el conjunto de arreglos donde se encuentras los caracteres válidos.
minusculas=('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
mayusculas=('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
enteros=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

with open("C:/Users/rayvi/Desktop/hola.txt","r") as file:
    data=file.read()
edges={                 #usamos mapas o diccionarios
       (1,(minusculas,mayusculas,enteros)):2, #Llamo las tuplas para comprobación
       (2,'a'):2,
       (2,'b'):3,
       (3,'b'):3,
       (3,'a'):4,
       (4,'c'):5}
aceptacion=[5]  #estado de aceptacion
def fsmsim(string, current, edges, aceptacion):#creamos la funcion
    if string == "":#cuando no encuentra nada
        return current in aceptacion #retorna true
    else:
        letter= string[0] # comienza con el primer caracter
        if(current,letter)in edges: #AQUI ES DONDE NO SE QUE HACER PARA COMPROBAR SI EL CARACTER EXISTE EN CADA TUPLA
            destination=edges[(current,letter)]#si es asi destination tendra el nuevo valor estado
            remaining_string=string[1:]#comenzara a recorrer los demas caracteres
            return fsmsim(remaining_string,destination,edges,aceptacion)#funcion recursiva
        else:
            return False #si no es asi retorna falso

#hacemos una prueba        
print(fsmsim(data,1,edges,aceptacion))
```

En este código, intento hacer lo mismo: Un automata que me compruebe la existencia de un valor, pero, que se encuentra dentro de un grupo de arreglos que están dentro de un diccionario, y no sé como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero daré una solución directa al problema que planteas. Después haré algunas sugerencias sobre cómo un cambio en la estructura de datos que usas (la variable `edges`) puede llevar a un código más simple y más rápido.

### Solución a tu problema

El problema es que si intentas `(current, letter) in edges` sólo te devolverá `True` si esa pareja de número y letra que es `(current, letter)` es una clave del diccionario. En tu caso eso funciona para las claves `(2,'a')`, por ejemplo, pero no para la primera, en la que si bien el primer elemento de la tupla es un entero, el segundo elemento en cambio no es una letra, sino una tupla con tres elementos cada uno de los cuales es a su vez una tupla de muchas letras o dígitos.

Para este caso la única solución es implementar una función que reciba el número y letra a buscar y lo busque recorriendo las claves del diccionario. Ya que algunas claves tienen una letra pero otras una tupla, hay que diferenciarlas dinámicamente mirando su tipo. Esta sería una posible implementación:

```
def find_key(letter, current, edges):
  for state, letters in edges:
    if current==state:
      if type(letters) == str:
        if letter == letters:
          return (state, letters)
      else:
        for grupo in letters:
          if letter in grupo:
            return (state,letters)
  return None
```

Esa función recibe como parámetros un número (`current`) y una letra (`letter`) y lo busca en la estructura de datos `edges`. Para ello recorre todas las claves de `edges`, cada una de las cuales es una tupla, y en cada una compara su primer elemento con `current` y en caso de que coincidan, mira si su segundo elemento es una letra, en cuyo caso la compara con `letter`. Si no es una letra, asumimos que es una lista de tuplas y entonces la recorremos para mirar si `letter` está en alguno de los grupos.

Si al final encontramos la letra, retornamos la pareja que hace de clave en el diccionario `edges`. Si no la encontramos retornamos `None`.

Esto se usaría desde la otra función así:

```
def fsmsim(string, current, edges, aceptacion):#creamos la funcion
    if string == "":#cuando no encuentra nada
        return current in aceptacion #retorna true
    else:
        letter= string[0] # comienza con el primer caracter
        key = find_key(letter, current, edges)
        if key: 
            destination=edges[key] #si es asi destination tendra el nuevo valor estado
            remaining_string=string[1:] #comenzara a recorrer los demas caracteres
            return fsmsim(remaining_string,destination,edges,aceptacion)#funcion recursiva
        else:
            return False #si no es asi retorna falso
```

### Propuesta de mejora 1

Primero tienes un error en la tupla `enteros`, pues contiene los números del 1 al 9 (falta el 0, no sé si por error o intencionadamente), pero no son caracteres, por lo que nunca encontrará el carácter `'1'` por ejemplo en esa lista.

Pero por otro lado, el almacenarlo como tres tuplas separadas complica el código ¿por que no una única tupla que tenga las mayúsculas más las minúsculas más los dígitos? O mejor aún ¿por qué no puede ser todo eso un string?

Esta es mi primera propuesta. Cambiar todas esas tuplas por el siguiente string:

```
import string
caracteres = string.ascii_letters + "123456789"
```

Ahora la estructura `edges` quedaría así:

```
edges={           
       (1,caracteres):2, 
       (2,'a'):2,
       (2,'b'):3,
       (3,'b'):3,
       (3,'a'):4,
       (4,'c'):5}
```

La función que busca la clave se simplifica enormemente:

```
def find_key(letter, current, edges):
  for state, letters in edges:
    if current==state and letter in letters:
      return (state, letters)
  return None
```

Desde la función `fsmsim` se sigue usando como antes.

### Mejora 2, optimización

El problema de la solución anterior es que para encontrar la clave tenemos que iterar por todas las claves del diccionario `edges`. Esto no es muy eficiente ya que precisamente los diccionarios existen para poder recuperar rápidamente de ellos una clave sin tener que iterar. Pero la forma en que está construido `edges` nos obliga a esta iteración.

Propongo entonces que `edges` sea un diccionario cuya clave sea sólo el estado (el entero) en lugar de la tupla (estado, letra). Su valor será otro diccionario en el que a cada letra corresponde un nuevo estado. Es decir, sería así:

```
edges={
    1: { letra: 2 for letra in caracteres },
    2: { 'a': 2,
         'b': 3,
       },
    3: { 'b': 3,
         'a': 4,
       },
    4: { 'c': 5,
       },
}
```

De este modo, entrando por el estado, sacamos ya otro diccionario que seguidamente direccionaríamos con la letra. Fíjate que para la clave 1 he usado una expresión generadora, que crea un sub-diccionario cuyas claves son ya las letras y dígitos y el estado es 2 para todos ellos. Es decir, este subdiccionario tendría 61 claves (las 26*2 letras más los 9 dígitos) y para cada una de esas claves, el valor 2.

Aunque esto es más ineficiente en términos de memoria, es más eficiente en tiempo de ejecución, pues ahora para recuperar un dato de ese diccionario sería tan simple como `edges[current][letter]`.

Sólo queda tener cuidado con el caso en que la clave buscada no exista. Para eso es conveniente usar `edges.get(current)` en lugar de `edges[current]`, pues usando `.get()` podemos especificarle un valor a retornar en caso de que la clave no se encuentre. Así podemos usar:

```
siguiente = edges.get(current, {}).get(letter, None)
```

Si `current` se encuentra, tendremos el diccionario interno sobre el cual buscar la letra. Si no se encuentra le pedimos que nos devuelva entonces `{}`, es decir, un diccionario vacío. En cualquier caso el resultado de ese primer `get()` es un diccionario, sobre el cual podemos hacer un segundo `get()` para buscar `letter`. En esta ocasión pedimos que si no encuentra esa letra en el diccionario retorne `None`.

Por tanto en la variable `siguiente` tendrás el siguiente estado, o bien `None`. Así que tu función quedaría:

```
def fsmsim(string, current, edges, aceptacion):#creamos la funcion
    print(current)
    if string == "":#cuando no encuentra nada
        return current in aceptacion #retorna true
    else:
        letter= string[0] # comienza con el primer caracter
        siguiente = edges.get(current, {}).get(letter, None)
        if siguiente:
            destination=siguiente #si es asi destination tendra el nuevo valor estado
            remaining_string=string[1:]#comenzara a recorrer los demas caracteres
            return fsmsim(remaining_string,destination,edges,aceptacion)#funcion recursiva
        else:
            return False #si no es asi retorna falso
```